# print flink KeyedStream

Tags: java, apache-flink

I have a `DataStream<Tuple2<String, Integer>>`

this prints correctly

when I key, window, sum then print nothing comes out?

so I take my working stream `stream` then run:

```
DataStream<Tuple2<String, Integer>> groupedStream = stream
        .keyBy(0)
        .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(5)))
        .sum(1);

groupedStream.print();
```

nothing appears in the `stdout`?
How can I debug this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the issues (like 95%) connected with lack of output after performing Window operator comes from the fact that You don't have proper Watermark assignment or timestamp extraction.

So:

1. If You have never called the `assignTimestampsAndWatermarks` on Your stream then You should do that.
2. If You have used the `AssignedWithPeriodicWatermark` then You should make sure that the`setAutoWatermarkInterval()` was not set to 0.
3. Verify that watermarks can be generated correctly (i.e. Your test data spans over 5 seconds)
4. Also, it may be worth to verify whether this works with `parallelism` equal to one as a safety check.

Comment: There is a default auto watermark interval of 100 msec, so setting it is not strictly necessary.

Comment: Switching to TumblingProcessingTimeWindows would be another solution.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Updated:)

Comment: I changed the `setAutoWatermarkInterval` and it worked thanks